Python AHK Window Click Is Not Working as Click doesn't Register
I'm using AHK with python I'm trying to send a click to a certain window without moving the mouse, the cursor does something but it doesn't send a click.
from ahk import AHK
import time

myK = AHK()


time.sleep(2)
win = myK.active_window

a=0

while a<3:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(myK.get_mouse_position())
    a+=1
    win.click(myK.get_mouse_position())


win.click expects two integer arguments. You only passed one tuple.
So, the corrected code is as follows:
    print(myK.get_mouse_position())
    a+=1
    x, y = myK.get_mouse_position()
    win.click(x, y)

Or alternatively:
    pos = myK.get_mouse_position()
    print(pos)
    a+=1
    win.click(pos.x, pos.y)

